# Why does memoizaion take more time than tabulation?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was trying to solve this basic Dynamic Programming problem of Coin Change:

Given a value N, if we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S = { S1, S2, .. , Sm} valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? The order of coins doesn’t matter.
Here is the solution that I could create :

I solved this problem with all the three general ways. ie. Recursion, DP-memoization, and DP-tabulation.

C++ implementation : https://ideone.com/14bBIv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int max2(int a, int b)
{
    return (a>b) ? a : b;
}

int max3(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if(a>c)
        return (a>b) ? a : b;
    else
        return (c>b) ? c : b;
}

int min3(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if(a<c)
        return (a<b) ? a : b;
    else
        return (c<b) ? c : b;
}


int Coins_rec(int * S, int m, int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;

    if(n < 0)
        return 0;

    if(m<=0 && n >=0){
        return 0;
    }

    return ( Coins_rec( S, m-1, n ) + Coins_rec( S, m, n - S[m-1] ) );
}


int memo[101][101] ;


int Coins_memoization(int * S, int m, int n)
{

    if(n == 0)
        return 1;

    if(n < 0)
        return 0;

    if(m<=0 && n >=0){
        return 0;
    }

    if(memo[m][n] !=-1) {

        return memo[m][n];
    } else
    {
        memo[m][n] = ( Coins_rec( S, m-1, n ) + Coins_rec( S, m, n - S[m-1] ) );
        return memo[m][n];
    }

}


int Coins_tabulation (int * S, int m, int n)
{
    int L[m+1][n+1] ;   //L[i][j] -> Minimum number of 'i' different types of coins required to make final amonut j
    int i, j;

    L[0][0] = 1;

    for(i=0;i<=m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=n;j++){
            if (i == 0 && j >= 0) {
                L[0][j] = 0;
            } else if (i > 0 && j == 0) {
                L[i][0] = 1;
            } else {
                L[i][j] = ( (i >= 1) ? L[i-1][j] : 0 ) + ( (j - S[i-1] >=0) ? L[i][j - S[i-1]] : 0 ) ;
            }
        }
    }
    return L[m][n];
}       // -----  end of function Coins_tabulation  ----- 




int main() {

    int arr[] = {2, 5, 3, 6};
    int m = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the amount" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i=0; i<=101; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=101; j++){
            memo[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    struct timeval t0; gettimeofday(&t0 , NULL);

    cout << "Number of Ways = " << Coins_rec(arr, m, n) << endl;
    struct timeval t1; gettimeofday(&t1 , NULL);
    cout << "recursion : " << (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) << " seconds and " << (t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) << " microseconds" << endl;

    cout << "Number of Ways (Memoization) = "  << Coins_memoization(arr, m, n) << endl;
    struct timeval t2; gettimeofday(&t2 , NULL);
    cout << "memoization : " << (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) << " seconds and " << (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) << " microseconds" << endl;


    cout << "Number of Ways (Tabulation) = "  << Coins_tabulation(arr, m, n) << endl;
    struct timeval t3; gettimeofday(&t3 , NULL);
    cout << "tabulation : " << (t3.tv_sec - t2.tv_sec) << " seconds and " << (t3.tv_usec - t2.tv_usec) << " microseconds" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

.
Below were the results :
(Inputs taken via stdin)

```
For n = 10
recursion : 0 seconds and 14 microseconds
memoization : 0 seconds and 17 microseconds
tabulation : 0 seconds and 17 microseconds

For n =100
recursion : 0 seconds and 1300 microseconds
memoization : 0 seconds and 1270 microseconds
tabulation : 0 seconds and 35 microseconds
```

What I am unable to understand , is that why for slightly larger input, memoization is taking almost same amount of time as simple recursive solution ? Shouldn't memoization take even lesser time than tabulation in this case, as it skips many useless calculations from the matrix, that have to be done in case of tabulation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are actually recursing into `Coins_rec` rather than `Coins_memoization` in your recursive step of the memoization algorithm. Once you fix that, you will find that for larger numbers memoization is indeed as fast as tabulation. For example, here are the results for 100 on my machine:

```
100
recursion : 0 seconds and 914 microseconds
memoization : 0 seconds and 18 microseconds
tabulation : 0 seconds and 16 microseconds
```

Comment: Lol....!!
That's embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out. I really wanted to upvote it. But can't do that due to <15 points. Marking it as "Correct Answer"

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should expect memoization to be asymptotically faster, but for tiny inputs which are solved in microseconds, all bets are off and which is actually faster will be highly hardware / system dependent.

Comment: True, I checked again after rectifying the problem identified by Maksim Solovjov.
.
For n=100
recursion : 0 seconds and 1287 microseconds
memoization : 0 seconds and 39 microseconds
tabulation : 0 seconds and 33 microseconds
.
And for n=1000
recursion : 9 seconds and 107929 microseconds
memoization : 0 seconds and 93 microseconds
tabulation : 0 seconds and 128 microseconds